How to update BIOS of Razer laptop without Windows?
A couple of weeks after I've installed Ubuntu 24.04 (and decided to have the installer completely wipe and take over the SSD) on my 2021 Razer Blade 15 Advanced, it has just occurred to me that I forgot to update the BIOS when I still had Windows on this thing. Is there a way that I can update it without Windows?

My dell system upgrades itself when firmware updates arrived from Dell. Ubuntu will warn me when an update is available & tell me I have to reboot to apply upgrade; and I need do nothing but reboot. You don't mention what Ubuntu 24.04 product you're using (Desktop? Server? flavor?) but I'd expect the Ubuntu system to upgrade when upgrades are available (unless you removed the firmware upgrade tool; the package is a snap package so disabling snap can prevent it from running on some releases, snap:firmware-updater stable/ubuntu-24.04 127)

This question is similar to: Firmware-updater user guide. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How to update the computer bios firmware without using Windows. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I do not see any Razor's in list so fwupdate will not work. https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devices/ Best to only buy systems that use fwupdate. Check user manual on UEFI update. Most vendors use Windows but also will update from a download file in a FAT32 partition. some also use a DOS  boot flash drive with the update file(s).
